# Sort slice of struct based order by number and alphabetically

Tags: sorting, go

I have a slice of struct like this and this data

```golang
type Interval struct{
    number     float64
    coordinate string
}

func GetIntervals() []Interval {

    data := []Interval{
        {number: 1, coordinate: "x"},
        {number: 8, coordinate: "y"},
        {number: 2, coordinate: "x"},
        {number: 5, coordinate: "y"},
        {number: 5, coordinate: "x"},
        {number: 6, coordinate: "y"},
        {number: 3, coordinate: "x"},
        {number: 7, coordinate: "y"},
    }
    return data
}
```

My question is how can I sort `[]Interval` by `number` and `coordinate`?

I have tried with below sort method, but it is not as my expectation

```golang
data := GetIntervals()
// sort method that I use
sort.Slice(data, func(i, j int) bool {
    return data[i].number < data[j].number
})
```

```
[{1 x} {2 x} {3 x} {5 y} {5 x} {6 y} {7 y} {8 y}] // result
[{1 x} {2 x} {3 x} {5 x} {5 y} {6 y} {7 y} {8 y}] // expectation
```

diff:
`{5 y} {5 x}` should be `{5 x} {5 y}`

My expectation result is similar with what python has with function `sort`
I appreciate any help

[Demo](https://go.dev/play/p/9H-Tk8Hgacl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparator function doesn't compare property `coordinate` in the situation property `number` is equal. Hence the position of {5, x} and {5, y} might be non-deterministic if the sorting algorithm is not stable.

Here is the updated version of the comparator function:

```
sort.Slice(data, func(i, j int) bool {
    if data[i].number != data[j].number {
        return data[i].number < data[j].number
    }
    return data[i].coordinate < data[j].coordinate
})
```

See [Demo with both sort functions](https://go.dev/play/p/iLCTzt2JgZ_s)

Comment: Thank you, this is woking as a charm. I missed the condition for checking the number. Thanks for the help